# kendo Datasource Post Method not invoked, Chart not Displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

My view image as you see I have declared my DataSource read method which is not working [image: Controller code]

Comment: add code instead of image

Comment: please add also client side call because just having a controller does not mean it's gonna get called